# How to change spacing between two ticks in matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some data that requires Day 0 to not be shown on the x-axis. The dataframe has no column for Day 0, but Matplotlib creates a space for it between day -1 and 1. I've looked through the documentation, but can't find a way to adjust spacing between only two ticks. The dataframe is:

```
group  stat   -1.0        1.0       2.0        3.0        4.0       5.0
abc    mean    8.362999  17.043362  3.526539  22.931884  10.835121  6.035011
abc     sem    1.481135   5.029173  0.822778  13.768812   2.149704  0.840965
abc     std    3.311919  11.245573  1.839788  30.787999   4.806885  1.880455
```

Code to plot:

```
df.set_index(['subject'], inplace=True)
df.drop(['group'],axis=1,inplace=True)
x = df.columns.values
y = df.loc['mean'].values
sem = df.loc['sem'].values
plt.errorbar(x, y, sem, color='#0075d9', marker='o', clip_on=False)
```

This is an example of the chart (please ignore the shading): 
[image]
You can see that it has more space between -1 and 1 than the other ticks. Is there a way to 'drop' the Day 0 tick from the X-axis?

Comment: Show your code to plot

Comment: It is a linear plot... so the step from -1 to 1 will be twice the step from 1 to 2...

Comment: In principle, you can create arbitrary scales with matplotlib, see [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/scales/custom_scale.html). For the use case here, it might be overkill. Instead why not name the `-1`-column `0`, and change the tick*label* that appears at 0 to `"-1"`?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I've added the plotting code above. The original dataframe had a day 0 column, which I removed by adding 1 to it, so I don't think I should rename -1 to 0. I'll try the suggestion of changing the tick labels instead of adding 1 to the column names.

Comment: Update: I ended up letting the column labels include day 0, and instead added 1 to each x-axis label to get rid of the day 0 label.